# Align 2 views bottoms but one is pushed lower further

Tags: android, android-layout

If I have a constraint layout like this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text = "Some text"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/preview"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/parent">

    />
    <Button
            android:layout_width="57dp"
            android:layout_height="281dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textview"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textview"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textview">

    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Where textview is another widget. then this will make the button and the textview bottom boundaries aligned.

Is there anyway where I can push button 10dp lower? So I want the button bottom to be anchored to the bottom of the textview however I wanted to be pushed a bit lower by 10dp. I tried to set the android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp" but that didn't work!
Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Where is the rest of the xml?

Answer (score 0):

use `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"` in your button layout

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a FrameLayout, with `layout_height="wrap_content"`. Then, set `layout_gravity="bottom"` on both the child Views. Give your TextView `layout_marginBottom="10dp"`.

The result should be something like (this is a skeleton with only the relevant attrs):

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        />
        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        />
    </FrameLayout>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I am sorry , I like to stay within constrain layout because my button is related to other views. It is very complex layout and I just posted the relevent part to the question

Comment: We really need the rest of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

in java or kotlin seet textview.bringToFront();

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="157dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text = "Some text"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#05afaf"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/button"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The button bottom will be at the same spot as textview bottom